# Model categories of simplicial objects

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, simplicial-stuff

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, then surely the category of simplicial
objects $s\mathcal{C}$ is not automatically a model category.  What conditions
must $\mathcal{C}$ satisfy in order for $s\mathcal{C}$ to have a reasonable model structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always has a model structure using Kan's theory of Reedy categories.  For a proof, see Hirschhorn *Model Categories and their Localizations* 15.3.

This is because $\Delta$ and $\Delta^{op}$ are both Reedy categories.

I will address the more general question as well:

If $C$ is any small category, the condition for $M^C$ to be a model category is that $M$ be cofibrantly generated.  However, it is not necessarily true that $M^C$ is itself cofibrantly generated.  In general, the condition we need for that is called combinatoriality.  However, the existence of such a cofibrantly generated model structure that is not combinatorial would disprove Vopenka's principle (a large cardinal axiom), so I cannot give an example of one.

Comment: I stand corrected and informed, thanks!

Comment: No      problem!

Comment: I thought the questions was: when does the category of simplicial objects in $\mathcal{C}$ have a model structure, _without assuming $\mathcal{C}$ is a model category._

Comment: I'm tempted to let you think that I asked the smartest possible question, but I didn't. I originally intended $\mathcal{C}$ to be any category.

But I think we can see that if $s\mathcal{C}$ has a model structure, 
then $\mathcal{C}$ must be complete-cocomplete, and then we can use the trivial structure on $\mathcal{C}$ and follow Harry's method.  So the question in which we assume a given model category on $\mathcal{C}$ is harder and more interesting, and what was answered.

Comment: @Jeff: True, but Charles also gave a very interesting answer that seems more in line with what you were trying to ask originally.  I would not be offended if you unaccepted my answer and accepted his.

Comment: The real question is: what is a "reasonable" model category structure on $s\mathcal{C}$?  What constraints should it satisfy?

Comment: Dear Charles, I had a comment to a similar effect that I deleted so my comment above (asking the OP to accept your answer) would rise to visibility.  

Comment: I am a bit confused, and this is probably just my ignorance, but how is $sC$ (simplicial objects in $C$) realized as $M^C$ where $M$ is a model category?

Comment: $M^{\Delta^{op}}$

Comment: But $C$ is fixed and we want to find a model category $M$ s.t. $M^C$ is $sC$. I certainly agree that $sC=C^{\Delta^{op}}$ but C isn't a model category, according to the question, and I thought $M$ was supposed to be.

Comment: @Sean: Look at Charles's comment.  It's not clear what the OP wants to consider to be a "reasonable model category".  As I said before in a deleted comment (that Jeff references), if a category D is complete-cocomplete, we can equip $sD=D^{\Delta^{op}}$ with the Reedy model structure attached to the trival one on $D$.  This isn't really a useful one, but it certainly is one.  

Answer (score 13):

Quillen gives a couple of sets of sufficient conditions for $s\mathcal{C}$ to be a model category, in his *Homotopical Algebra* book.  Notably, this includes the case when $\mathcal{C}$ is a complete and cocomplete category with a small set of projective generators.  This gives model structures for categories of simplicial groups, simplicial rings, simplicial lie algebras, etc.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting! What page is this on?

Comment: Ah, got it. It's $II.4$.